Rosbridge Certificate
I'm trying to use rosbridge_server with a certificate downloaded using Certbot (standalone with my own domain) and I'm getting an error related to permissions.
After this I've copied the certificate and the key to another folder and the launch worked but I need to give permission every time I connect.
Is there any tutorial or guide that I can use?
